# Fill missing values with a calculated next value

Tags: r, date, tidyr, na, lubridate

I have a data frame with a date column with some missing values:

```
my_df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2020-07-01", NA, NA, NA, "2022-07-01", "2023-07-01")))
my_df
#         date
# 1 2020-07-01
# 2       <NA>
# 3       <NA>
# 4       <NA>
# 5 2022-07-01 # NAs to be replaced with 2022-07-01 minus one year
# 6 2023-07-01
```

I want to fill in the `NA` dates thus:

- fill with next non-`NA`, upwards
- subtract 1 year from the filled values.

Desired result:

```
data.frame(date = as.Date(c("2020-07-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-07-01", "2022-07-01", "2023-07-01")))

#         date
# 1 2020-07-01
# 2 2021-07-01 
# 3 2021-07-01 
# 4 2021-07-01 
# 5 2022-07-01
# 6 2023-07-01
```

I like `tidyverse` so I'm hoping to use `fill()` and something like `%m-% years(1)` from lubridate. My attempt:

```
my_df <- my_df %>%
  mutate(date2 = date %m-% years(1)) %>%
  fill(date2, .direction = "up") %>%
  mutate(date = if_else(is.na(date), date2, date)) %>%
  select(-date2)
```

seems to work, but is there a more direct method?

Answer (score 1):

An option with `zoo`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)

my_df %>% mutate(date = na.locf(date, fromLast = TRUE) %m-% years(1 * is.na(date)))
```

Output:

```
        date
1 2020-07-01
2 2021-07-01
3 2021-07-01
4 2021-07-01
5 2022-07-01
6 2023-07-01
```

Comment: OH YES I remember na.locf() now - I think I used it a few years ago on a different project. Thank you.